# production pem file not able to send the notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pem

I have generated "production push notification certificate" and generated pem file. While testing APNS online the notifications are being sent only when I select "sandbox" option and not sending notification when selected "production".

So my question is why ""production certificate" is sending in notification when selected "sandbox", and not sending the notification when selected "production" option.

Comment: Error: {"statusCode":8,"statusMessage":"Invalid token"} this error I am getting when production option is selected

Comment: i think your fcm token is not valid for production option can you please share your code

Comment: Create an Adhoc/Production build of your app and try sending notifications.